# Bitbake/Yocto how to use older downloads of previous build to decrease Linux build time

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, bitbake

Hi I am building Linux for rasberry pi3 using yacto/bitbake, Is there a way to re-use sources/code downloaded for previous build to decrease the overall download time so that they are not fetched again whenever we create a new build directory. I know there is a `SSTATE_DIR` variable in `local.conf` which accelerate builds based on previously built output but I am looking for something to decrease the download time if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty the same as for `SSTATE_DIR` - you need variable [DL_DIR](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=dl_dir#term-DL_DIR) in `local.conf`. Here is some docs from `local.conf`:

```
#
# Where to place downloads
#
# During a first build the system will download many different source code tarballs
# from various upstream projects. This can take a while, particularly if your network
# connection is slow. These are all stored in DL_DIR. When wiping and rebuilding you
# can preserve this directory to speed up this part of subsequent builds. This directory
# is safe to share between multiple builds on the same machine too.
#
# The default is a 'downloads' directory under TOPDIR which is the build directory.
#
DL_DIR = .....
```

In `DL_DIR` you can use other Yocto global variables, for example [TOPDIR](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=dl_dir#term-TOPDIR). My `DL_DIR` looks like this

```
DL_DIR = "${TOPDIR}/../downloads"
```

so directory `downloads` is located next by `build` directory.

More that that, if you have several clones of Yocto project on the same PC, you can share `DL_DIR` across them all. Specifying path to some symlink as `DL_DIR` also works stable... just in case)